# Eliminating duplicate rows with null values using with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, common-table-expression, distinct-values

How do we eliminate duplicates by only selecting those with values in a certain field using with clause statement?

Query is something like this:

```
with x as (--queries with multiple join tables, etc.)
select distinct * from x
```

Output below:

```
Com_no   Company      Loc    Rewards
1         Mccin      India      50
1         Mccin      India
2         Rowle      China      18
3         Draxel     China      11
3         Draxel     China  
4         Robo       UK
```

As you can see, I get duplicate records. I want to get rid of the null values that are NOT unique. That is to say, Robo is unique since it only has 1 record with a null value in Rewards, so I want to keep that.

I tried this:

```
 with x as (--queries with multiple join tables, etc.)
 select distinct * from x where Rewards is not null
```

And of course that wasn't right, since it also got rid of `4 Robo UK`

Expected output should be:

```
1         Mccin      India      50
2         Rowle      China      18
3         Draxel     China      11 
4         Robo       UK
```

Comment: what should the expected output be?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Hi , I added expected output. Was wondering if we can still use and select from with clause population

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  One method is to use `row_number()`.  If you want only one value per `Com_no`/`Company`/`Loc`, then:

```
select x.*
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Com_no, Company, Loc order by Rewards nulls last) as seqnum
      from x
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or even:

```
select Com_no, Company, Loc, max(Rewards)
from x
group by Com_no, Company, Loc;
```

Comment: These works as long as the requirement is to just return the max value for com_no, company and Loc. That wasn't the requirement stated though. Does 'duplicate' not include the rewards column? Put another way, if India has a row with a Rewards value of 10, should it be included in the results or not @BFF?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're calling those rows duplicates, but they're not duplicates. They're different. So what you want to do is exclude rows where `Rewards` is null UNLESS there aren't any rows with a not null value, and then select the distinct rows. So something like:

```
select distinct * 
from x a
where Rewards is not null 
or (Rewards is null and not exists (select 1 from x b where a.Com_no = b.Com_no 
    and b.Rewards is not null)
```

Now your Robo row will still be included as there isn't a row in x for Robo where Rewards is not null, but the rows for the other Companies with null Rewards will be excluded as there are not null rows for them.

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't work for me. It didn't include Robo

Comment: Oh sorry. Edited SQL.